# dll replace in a big system

Tags: visual-c++, dll

When change the dll, I have to put it in a directory from where the system loads into memory. The problem is that everytime I change it, I have to close the system, replace the dll with a new one and start the system. It takes around 15/20 minutes which isvery long.

Can anyone tell me how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

When you quickly want to switch DLL versions, place the DLL in the same directory as the executable or provide a path to the directory where you switch your DLLs in Project Settings -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Environment. Then you don't have to mess with you Windows System directory.

However, Microsoft states [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If a DLL with the same module name is already loaded in memory, the system checks only for redirection and a manifest before resolving to the loaded DLL, no matter which directory it is in. The system does not search for the DLL.

You could try if [AlwaysUnloadDLL](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/667/) works for you.

Comment: The Directory in which Visual Studio places the dlls is fixed, I can't change it. The directory from where the system picks up dlls is also fixed and can't be altered. What I need here is some kind of batch program or any utility program, that will kill the processes accessing the dlls, then replace the dlls and then restart the program.

Comment: You mean the DDLs which are already loaded into memory? When they are not loaded already, my answer actually applies. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx and a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518228/is-it-possible-to-add-a-directory-to-dll-search-path-from-a-batch-file-or-cmd-sc
If this is not what you are looking for, please explain your problem more clear.

Comment: That Microsoft link is very helpful. I mean the DLLs which are already loaded into memory. I want to replace the DLL files and reload again into memory.